# Access n-th token in JSON

Tags: json, go

How can I access the *n-th* token in a JSON in Go?

Let's say I want to access the `b`'s value in `{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}`.
(5th token)

I thought of the following code, but is there any idiomatic/efficient way to achieve this?

```
func main() {
    const jsonStream = `{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}`
    dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(jsonStream))

    n := 5 // n-th token
    var t json.Token
    var err error
    for i := 1; i <= n; i++ {
        t, err = dec.Token() // just consume the first token until n-th one.
        if err != nil {
            log.Panicln(err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("value of b is", t)
}
```

Comment: Value of b is the token no. 8, parsing JSON is easy so you can write a little lexer that will do this task. The standard library does not expose parsing internals.

Comment: @JakubDóka Why the value of b (`2`) is 8th token? Doesn't `Decoder.Token()` return the tokens one by one? And, yes, we can parse JSON, but if the JSON is **very large** and if I want to get just the 5th token, then parsing the whole JSON would be very inefficient. This question is not related to typical JSON parsing (using `json.Unmarshal`).

Comment: you have `{`, `"a"`, `:`, `1`, `,`, `"b"`, `:` and then `2`. And lexer usually works like a lazy token stream from which you can take one token at a time. All you need to do is implement it.